# wind noise without input device

Tags: 20.04, sound, microphone

when I go to the settings menu it says that there is a maxed out mic input, even though there isn't anything plugged in. This must be something hardware side, as I have no issues when running windows 10. I'm running ubuntu 20.04 on a seperate drive from windows

Comment: Any electronic circuit has noise. If you amplify this, you'll get NOISE. Go back to the microphone settings an reduce tje gain (turn down the volume).

Comment: Welcome to the modern world. Microphones are everywhere more than you think. Check [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ozIKwGt38LQ) out. And I do not know why they are doing.